# Android: animate GridView childs has a strange behaviour in some devices

Tags: android, animation, gridview

I have a `GridView` whose childs are `ImageViews`. It's a 3x3 `GridView`. If the user presses a certain `Button` I change the order of these childs (randomly).

To make it more dynamic I decided to apply an animation when the user clicks the Button. Before placing each child to its final position I move them to three random positions inside the screen. So at the end, when the user clicks the Button, each ImageView (child) moves to three random positions and then goes to its final position in the GridView.

I tested this animation on my Galaxy S and some similar devices and it worked fine. But today I tested it in a Galaxy S III and something weird happens: all the images move **except the first one (mGrid.getChildAt(0))**. The first child stays at its position (0,0) and, when the animation ends, it moves directly to its final position. To make it even more weird, I checked the ImageView position during the animation and it says the image is moving!

To do the animation I'm using TweenEngine (http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/):

```
        for(int n=0; n<3; n++){
            Timeline parallel = tl.beginParallel();

            for(int i=0; i<mGrid.getChildCount(); i++){ 
                int x = r.nextInt(width);
                int y = r.nextInt(height);

                parallel.push(Tween.to(mGrid.getChildAt(i), ViewAccessor.POSITION_XY, 0.35f).target(x, y));

            }

            parallel.end();
        }
```

In my ViewAccessor I'm using target.setX and target.setY. To check if the ImageView has moved I use getX() and getY().

Anybody knows why is this happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to force view refresh with invalidate() method.
something like this:

```
mGridView.invalidate();
```

See if it helps.

Comment: I didn't expect such a simple answer to work, but it does! Thank you a lot! :)